# duplicate key value violates unique constraint error in django in a many-to-one relationship

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I'm trying to set-up a database in django, given the following relationships:

```
class Team(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table = '"teams"'

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False, max_length=100)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='TeamMember', related_name='members', related_query_name='members')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='created_teams', related_query_name='created_teams')
    team_admins = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='TeamAdmin', related_name='admin_teams', related_query_name='admin_teams')

class User(AbstractUser):
    class Meta:
        db_table = '"users"'
    
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, unique=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

In essence, I want to set-up a many-to-one relationship between the class User and the class Team via "Creator". A Team can only have one Creator user, but a single user can be the Creator for multiple Teams. To do that, I'm using models.ForeignKey.

However, whenever I try to create an additional team using the same user, I get the error: "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "teams_creator_id_key"". Is there something wrong with how I set up this many-to-one relationship?

I've tried setting the ForeignKey definition with unique=False, removing that flag altogether, and nothing seems to work. As a sidenote, to create a new Team im using a serializer with the following code:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.get(id=self.context['user_id'])
        team: Team = Team.objects.create(
            name = validated_data.get('name'),
            creator = user,
        )
        team_admin: TeamAdmin = TeamAdmin.objects.create(
            team = team,
            admin = user
        )
        team_member: TeamMember = TeamMember.objects.create(
            team = team,
            member = user
        )
        return team
```

TeamAdmin and TeamMember are other tables in my database. I'm getting the user_id from the request JWT token, and have verified that this part is working properly.

Comment: did you run makemigrations and migrate after changing to `unique=False`?